# Issue with javascript form not saving answers

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this form that I'm trying to embed onto my website.

- I want it to be able to store the answers to the questions, such that you can click "back" and the highlighted option is the one you chose.
- I also need them to save to I can then programatically redirect the user to a page depending on how many answers she got right.

Problem:

- Right now the answers aren't being saved at all.
- It MIGHT be related to the event listeners, as I had a console.log
  and it was only registering the answer to the first question, but not
  subsequent ones.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

```html
<style>
/* CSS Styles for the quiz - Customize as needed */

/* Styling for the quiz container */
#quizContainer {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 600px; /* Set a maximum width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container */
}

/* Styling for the title and subtitle */
#titleContainer {
  background-color: #dfedef; /* Background color for title and subtitle */
  padding: 5px 20px; /* Added top and bottom padding */
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center; /* Center align the text */
}

/* Styling for the question number and question */
#questionContainer {
  background-color: #fcfaf7; /* Background color */
  padding: 10px; /* Added padding */
  border-radius: 10px; /* Added border radius */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* Added margin */
}

/* Styling for the title */
h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em; /* Half the original size */
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #2d536a; /* Changed title color */
}
#age {
  font-size: 0.8em; /* 3/4 of the current size */
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #b95966; /* Color for "15-18 meses" */
  margin-top: 0;
}

/* Styling for Yes/No buttons */
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none; /* Hide default radio buttons */
}
label.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 6px 16px; /* Adjusted padding */
  border: 1px solid #2d536a; /* Changed outline color */
  border-radius: 5px; /* Adding border radius */
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label.btn {
  background-color: #63a3ad; /* Changed background color when selected */
  color: white; /* Changed text color */
}

/* Styling for Previous/Next buttons */
#prevBtn,
#nextBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 45px; /* Increased margin */
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 6px 16px; /* Adjusted padding */
  background-color: #63a3ad; /* Changed background color */
  color: white; /* Changed text color */
  border: none; /* Removed outline */
  border-radius: 5px; /* Adding border radius */
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 20px; /* Adjusting font size */
  vertical-align: middle; /* Aligns buttons vertically */
}
</style>

<div id="quizContainer">
  <div id="titleContainer">
    <h1>Hitos del lenguaje<br><span id="age">15-18 meses</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionContainer">
    <p><strong>Question 1:</strong><br>Is the sky blue?</p>
  </div>
  <form id="quizForm">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="yes" name="q1" value="yes">
      <label for="yes" class="btn">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="no" name="q1" value="no">
      <label for="no" class="btn">No</label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn">&larr;</button> <!-- Left arrow character -->
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn">&rarr;</button> <!-- Right arrow character -->
  </form>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let questionNumber = 1;
  const questions = [
    "Is the sky blue?",
    "Do you like pizza?",
    "Have you traveled abroad?",
    "Do you enjoy reading?"
  ];
  const selectedAnswers = {}; // Object to store selected answers

  document.getElementById('nextBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const answer = document.querySelector('input[name="q' + questionNumber + '"]:checked');
    if (answer) {
      selectedAnswers[questionNumber] = answer.value; // Save selected answer
    }

    if (questionNumber < questions.length) {
      questionNumber++;
      document.getElementById('questionContainer').innerHTML = "<p><strong>Question " + questionNumber + ":</strong><br>" + questions[questionNumber - 1] + "</p>";
      const selected = selectedAnswers[questionNumber]; // Get selected answer if exists
      const radio = document.querySelector('input[name="q' + questionNumber + '"][value="' + selected + '"]');
      if (radio) {
        radio.checked = true; // Set previously selected answer as checked
      } else {
        // If no previous answer, clear the selection
        const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="q' + questionNumber + '"]');
        radios.forEach(radio => radio.checked = false);
      }

      if (questionNumber === questions.length) {
        document.getElementById('nextBtn').innerText = 'See Results';
      }
    } else {
      // Redirect to results page based on scores or selected answers
      // Use selectedAnswers object to determine the result
      // For example:
      console.log(selectedAnswers); // Display selected answers in the console
    }
  });
  
  document.getElementById('prevBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (questionNumber > 1) {
      questionNumber--;
      document.getElementById('questionContainer').innerHTML = "<p><strong>Question " + questionNumber + ":</strong><br>" + questions[questionNumber - 1] + "</p>";
      const selected = selectedAnswers[questionNumber]; // Get selected answer if exists
      const radio = document.querySelector('input[name="q' + questionNumber + '"][value="' + selected + '"]');
      if (radio) {
        radio.checked = true; // Set previously selected answer as checked
      } else {
        // If no previous answer, clear the selection
        const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="q' + questionNumber + '"]');
        radios.forEach(radio => radio.checked = false);
      }

      if (questionNumber === questions.length - 1) {
        document.getElementById('nextBtn').innerText = 'Next';
      }
      if (questionNumber === 1) {
        document.getElementById('prevBtn').style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

When I click "back", I expect the highlighted option to be the one I selected. However, it appears the answers aren't being saved, as the selected option is just the same for all questions.

Comment: You need to store the answers in localstorage. Please refere this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).

Comment: @SrushtiShah it's not about the browser's navigation button "back", it's about the `prevBtn` in their HTML. No local storage needed here, it's all on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

In the event handler for the `Next` button, you have

```js
const answer = document.querySelector('input[name="q' + questionNumber + '"]:checked');
```

This gets the radio button that has been checked for this question. But, if you look at the selector, the selector effectively changes for every question - `input[name="q1"]`, `input[name="q2"]`, etc.

So, to fix this problem, you just need to change the names of both radio buttons after the next button is clicked.

```js
if (answer) {
  selectedAnswers[questionNumber] = answer.value; // Save selected answer

  // Update the input elements.
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(inputElement => {
    inputElement.name = `q${questionNumber + 1}`;
  });
}
```

Not only does this fix the issue with answers being selected, it will also reset the inputs when question changes (which doesn't happen in your code).

Aside - You need to add similar logic to the `Previous` button handler, along with checking the radio button if answer had already been selected for that question.